# InvalidCastException trying to cast from a boxed int to a nullable enum

Tags: c#, generics, casting, enums, nullable

I have an enum, `Foo`:

```
public enum Foo { Alpha, Bravo, Charlie }
```

If I attempt the following cast from a boxed `int` to a `Foo?`, I get an `InvalidCastException`:

```
var x = (Foo?)(object)1;
```

This led me to some experimentation...

```
var x = (Foo)(object)1; // succeeds
var x = (long)(object)1; // fails
var x = (long?)(object)1; // fails
var x = (long)1; // succeeds
var x = (long?)1; // succeeds
var x = (int)(object)1; // succeeds
var x = (int?)(object)1; // succeeds
```

What this tells me is that you can cast from a boxed `int` to an enum but not to a `long`, and you *cannot* convert from a boxed `int` to any kind of nullable except an `int?`.

By the way, the reason I'm casting the `int` to `object` first is that I'm really trying to cast from an `int` to a generic parameter `TValue`, like this:

```
var x = (TValue)(object)1;
```

If I didn't have `(object)`, it wouldn't compile. (See this [blog post by Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/07/10/when-is-a-cast-not-a-cast.aspx) for details.)

**Questions**

1. Why can you convert from a boxed `int` to an enum, but not to a nullable enum (and not to a `long` nor a `long?`)?
2. What's the easiest way to rewrite `var x = (TValue)(object)1;` so that it compiles, works at runtime, and is performant (assuming `TValue` is determined to be a `Foo?` at runtime)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the first question, you can convert from a boxed value to an enum only if the boxed value is of the enum's underlying type.  Had you declared

```
enum Foo : byte { ...
```

you would not be able to cast from boxed int to Foo.

To answer the second question, try

```
var x = (TValue)Enum.ToObject(typeof(TValue), 1);
```

This involves boxing, though; if you need a solution that won't box, it will be more complicated.

Comment: That definitely appears to be the rule...I was wondering why that was so.

Comment: @DanM Not sure about that -- it's no doubt the same reason you can't go directly from (for example) boxed byte to unboxed int.  I'm not sure why the language designers decided that way, but Eric Lippert has written about it a few times and may have mentioned some reasons.

Comment: If `TValue` is a `Foo?`, I get "Type provided must be an Enum". However, there's an easy fix for this: `var x = (TValue)Enum.ToObject(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(TValue)), 1);`. Anyway, this is helpful. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Nullables are not some special category of atomic types, but shorthand for type `Nullable<T>`, which is why you can't cast a boxed int to a nullable enum.  If you want to create a nullable enum, you can do it thusly:

```
var x = new Nullable<Foo>((Foo)1);
```

This answers both your questions, I think!

Comment: Thanks, but this definitely doesn't answer my second question because it needs to be generic (i.e., replace `Nullable<Foo>` with `TValue`).

Comment: @DanM the problem with generic enums (well, one problem) is that you can't know what the underlying type is.  The direct cast can only succeed if the source value is of the same type.  Use static methods of the Enum and/or Convert classes instead.