# Casting as Nullable<T> causes an InvalidCastException to be thrown

Tags: c#

This function throws an InvalidCastException when the argument is a Nullable.  Why is that an error, and what can the caller do to avoid it?

```
static void TestFunction<T>(out T arg)
{
    arg = default(T);
    object o = 1;
    arg = (T)o;
}
```

[Gist to reproduce the problem](https://gist.github.com/jmcgill-public/332822f40c3622c7cb80#file-casterrorexample-cs)

Comment: It works fine on nullable ints, just not nullable enums.  Interesting...

Comment: If you use `ArgType.A` instead of 1 when assigning to `o`, it seems to work for me. Don't know why it doesn't work with 1.

Comment: Also fascinating: If you put (T)o in the watch window, it works fine.  So the debugger thinks the cast is okay.

Comment: *BAM*  Here is why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291223/invalidcastexception-trying-to-cast-from-a-boxed-int-to-a-nullable-enum